# Ejabberd right hook to find the user login

Tags: ejabberd

For detecting the user login the right hook looks like **user_available_hook** from the name. But this post [Intercept login/logout ejabberd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392326/intercept-login-logout-ejabberd) uses **set_presence_hook**. Which hook is the right hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `user_available_hook` as it is called only on the first available presence of the user. `set_presence` can be called in some cases on presence change and it is probably not what you want.